# Codemagic : no Explore Build Machine via SSH or VNC Client

Tags: ios, flutter, build, ipa, codemagic

I tried to use codemagic for my flutter app to run in on iOS. Successfully builded the application, but there is no option for [Explore Build Machine via SSH or VNC Client], which i gonna run from VNC. I watched it from this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3_6z2wfHiY

Is there any way to show the IP/ Go premium?

Thanks

Trying to find the docs, but not finding the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Forget to check when building the Apps. LOL

Comment: Add your answer in comment and if resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).